# Обособление пояснительных однородных членов

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите пожалуйста! Как оформить следующее предложение?

Запорный орган вращается в корпусе в двух взаимно перпендикулярных седлах — цилиндрическом и торцевом, — поэтому заклинивание запорного органа в корпусе исключено.

Изначально было:

Запорный орган вращается в корпусе в двух взаимно перпендикулярных седлах: цилиндрическом и торцевом, поэтому заклинивание запорного органа в корпусе исключено.

Может это правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что следует поставить одно тире: "Запорный орган вращается в корпусе в двух взаимно перпендикулярных седлах — цилиндрическом и торцевом, поэтому заклинивание запорного органа в корпусе исключено".

Второе тире как бы поглощается запятой. Постановка одного тире возможна при обособлении пояснительных членов и приложений, в то время как   два тире ставятся при обособлении вставных конструкций.

Answer (score 1):

По моему, после "седлах" следует писать " а именно:...", поскольку дальше следует перечисление. Но оно опущено, поэтому его заменяет тире. Перед "а" должна стоять запятая, вот ее-то надо поставить. Итак, "...седлах, - цилиндрическом и торцевом, поэтому заклинивание..."

Comment: Мне кажется, в таких случаях запятая поглощается.

Comment: Если вообще не иметь в виду "а именно:", то правильным должен быть изначальный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, нужно одно тире. Поясняются однородные члены, а не предложение после него. Как верно отметила Vera, второе тире ставится при вставной конструкции.

Answer (score 0):

"Цилиндрическом и торцевом" -это определения к слову "седлах". Валгина (http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-024.htm#i14096) пишет: "Обособление постпозитивных одиночных согласованных определений обязательно... если перед определяемым словом уже есть определение,[перпендикулярных ] и, следовательно, постпозитивные определения в какой-то мере становятся дополнительной характеристикой, добавочным уточнением: Первая моя московская осень, теплая и приветливая, стояла долго (Чив.). Возможно употребление тире перед обособленными определениями, стоящими в конце предложения: Таковы многие бунинские персонажи - колоритные, яркие, своеобычные (Кр.); Он еще долго стоял - опустошенный, ненавидящий себя (Расп.); Повернувшись к окну, он смотрел в сад - неуютный, голый, заштрихованный мелким, плотным дождем (Ард.).

Следовательно, надо написать так:

Запорный орган вращается в корпусе в двух взаимно перпендикулярных седлах — цилиндрическом и торцевом, поэтому заклинивание запорного органа в корпусе исключено.